# Design code to avoid rewriting during maintenance

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have `lens` based code that expects a certain data structure:

```
makeLenses ''Pool
...
pool ^. objects ^? _head :: Maybe Object
```

This code assumes that:

```
objects ::
  Functor f =>
  ([Object] -> f [Object]) -> Pool -> f Pool
```

But I want to introduce new information to the structure and new lens will become:

```
objects ::
  Functor f =>
  ([DebugInfo Object] -> f [DebugInfo Object]) -> Pool -> f Pool
```

My goal is to avoid any changes existing code as if it were complex project under maintenance.

Since I use `lens` library, I suppose it should be possible to provide a new module providing a "backported" `objects` lens so that I do not need to change old code (except imports maybe).

Is this plausible approach? Is there is a limitation lurking somewhere? Type classes or module system come to mind. I also suspect that I may have a problem with old code being unable to "reconstruct" a new structure. Do I need row type polymorphism to do that?

Lastly, if this can be done, how should I structure my modules to keep proper separation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to modify the `objects` function instead of creating a new one. However, for your last question : old code  reconstructing the new structure , the standard way is to have a default value and build any new values using this value and modifying it , like

```
data Foo = Foo { foo :: String, bar :: Int }
fooDef = Foo "" 0

newFoo :: String -> Int -> Foo
newFoo f b= fooDef { foo = f, bar = b }
```

This way, when you add a new field to `Foo` you only need to upade `fooDef`. However, it's probably better to not use it and update manually the code whereever it break. That's why you are using static typing after all, aren't you ?